# why doesn't popup() increment variable c?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, intervals

I am a beginner with Javascript.

Why won't `c` go up every time `popup()` is called?

I used `document.write` to see if it would go up but it stays with 1.

```
<script>

    var c = 0;



window.onload=function()
{
    var myVar = setInterval('popup()',2000);

    c++;
    document.write(c);
    if(c>2)
    {
    clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}

function popup()
{
    alert('hallo');

}

</script>
```

Code where interval won't stop after c>2.

```
<script>

var c = 0;
var myVar = null;

window.onload=function()
{
    myVar = setInterval('popup()',2000);
}

function popup()
{
    alert('hallo');
    c++;
    document.write(c);
    if(c>2)
    {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At loading of your page, you call setInterval.

So, every two seconds, you will call the popup function, which says 'hallo'.

Then, you increment your variable, etc...

=> To get your `c` variable incremented, increment it in the popup function.

*EDIT:*
To answer the comment with a better layout:

```
setInterval() returns an interval ID, which you can pass to clearInterval():

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(fname, 10000);

/* later */

clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
```

Comment: Thanks but now I got a other problem.

My interval won't stop after c>2

Comment: Add also the check in the function ;-)

Comment: Hi, yeah I did but it still doesn't work, sorry man really simple questions!

Comment: No problem. See edit above for the answer (with layout).

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it won't work i'll edit my code to what I have now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise c in your function:

```
function popup()
{
    alert('hallo');
    c++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At `window.onload`, you are calling `setInternal` method in which you are calling `popup` function.
So you need increment and print `c`in `popup` function. Also, `clearInterval` needs to be called in `popup` function as well.

```
<script>
    var c = 0,
        myVar;
    window.onload = function () {
        myVar = setInterval(popup, 2000);
    }

    function popup() {
        //alert('hello');
        c++;
        document.write(c);
        if (c > 2) {
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }
    }
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaNjn/

Answer (score 0):

Your window.onload function is called only once when page loads. You must increment a check c in your popup function

```
var c = 0;
var myVar = null;

window.onload=function()
{
    myVar = setInterval('popup()',2000);
}

function popup()
{
    alert('hallo');
    c++;
    document.write(c);
    if(c>2)
    {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, but now my interval won't stop even after c>2.